# Redirecting to the previous page in PHP

Tags: php

Im aware `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` has some security concerns attached to it. However I need to drive a user back to the page he has come from. Just wanted to understand if I store the the page that user came in a cookie and after may be a sign in use the cookie information to redirect the user back to the page? Does that sound secure? Like to here if you have a better suggestion for me? Thank you.

Comment: What if you just do it from the client side? `history.go(-1)`

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not 100% reliable. You could use sessions too.

Comment: Make the return page submit a query parameter when they submit, .e.g `/formhandler.php?return_to=%2Fnews.php`

Comment: if somebody want to change the `HTTP_REFERER` you can consider it as users own fault. If he want to change the url, he can direct call it in the browser. So i wouldn't consider this as insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. I would do it server side.

Example:

```
class Page
  {    

    public function define()
      {
         empty( $_SESSION['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) && $_SESSION['SCRIPT_NAME'] = 'http://example.com'; // default page
         in_array( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $this->defined()) && $_SESSION['RECOIL_PAGE'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // if the current page is in allowed list, make it recoil page (let user return to it)
      }

    public function defined()
      {
        return array(
            '/index.php',
            '/categories.php',
            '/videos.php',
            '/upload.php'
        );
      }

    public function recoil()
      {
        header( 'Location: ' . $_SESSION['RECOIL_PAGE'] );
        exit;
      }
  }
```

Usage:

- On load: `$this->page->define();` // To check if the page should be set as allowed, recoil page
- On execute: `$this->page->recoil();` // To redirect a user to the possible recoil page, if not in the list, then redirect to default one

Comment: Guess since I have a limited number of pages in total I can use this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No its okay, just inform the user that he is being redirected back, It is always used in OAuth, as return url, remember in Facebook, Google or twitter login in any app.

Just make sure that you really intended the user to go back where he come from.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is safe. Although our site is using session to redirect the user back to the previous page after login. It has the same effect as using a cookie.

Using `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is not reliable. Sometimes it may contain an invalid value. So it's not recommended.